# How can I deal with Unicode code points?

Tags: php, unicode, internationalization, sanitization

Let's say a user submits a comment and I want to obtain the array of Unicode code points of its value, select what code points are invalid and discard them, and save the comment.
How can I do that?

e.g.

The user submits "hello", and I want to obtain an array `$codepoints` with the following values:

```
$codepoints[0] = 0068
$codepoints[1] = 0065
$codepoints[2] = 006C
$codepoints[3] = 006C
$codepoints[4] = 006F
```

And, for some strange reason, I don't want to allow the letter "l", so I want to discard the characters with the code point U+006C. So the saved comment would be "heo".
Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395832/how-to-get-code-point-number-for-a-given-character-in-a-utf-8-string

Comment: better to use mb_convert_encoding if you have multibyte installed.  Code points are what you get after decoding UTF-8 or UTF-16LE/BE.  Code points are generally represent by a 24bit integer, but most systems for speed, use 32bit integers to represent a code point.  Characters can be one or more code points, depending on marks on the glyph.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with unicode literals.

```
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
mb_regex_encoding('utf-8');
echo mb_ereg_replace('[•]', '', '•T•e•s•t•');
```

This will output the string `Test`.

If you'd rather write the code points in hex, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805802/php-convert-unicode-codepoint-to-utf-8#7153133) may be useful.