# PHP: how to get unicode character code

Tags: php, unicode, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get code point number for a given character in a utf-8 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395832/how-to-get-code-point-number-for-a-given-character-in-a-utf-8-string)

I would like to create a tool that would convert a regular char to the utf code

**For example**: How to get U+00C0 from the input: a (in php)?

Comment: true, sorry, didn't now how to search properly. Thanks for the pointer!