# Does character encoding differ in Javascript and PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, encoding, character

I need to generate a "random" 128 byte key (Strength of randomness is not important at the moment). I do this in Javascript with the following code:

```
var buffer = "";
for(var i=0; i<128; i++)
{
    buffer += String.fromCharCode(Math.round(Math.random()*255));
}
```

However, when I send this key to a PHP script via POST, I find that certain characters in my key do not have the same encoding! For example when I output the encoding of ò in Javascript I get 254, yet the same character has an encoding of 195 in PHP.

Certain characters, such as A-Z, a-z, and 0-9 have the same encoding in both Javascript and PHP.

To output character codes, I use Javascript's .charCodeAt() method and PHP's ord() function.

I was hoping someone could explain to me why the character encodings differ. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't need 255 different chars, `127` should be easiest to work with because of PHP's notion of chars as bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascripts `.charCodeAt()` returns the Unicode code point for each string character. Strings in Javascript use UCS-2 or UTF-16.

PHP on the other hand only treats strings as streams of bytes. It doesn't know much of charsets actually. Basically it considers strings ASCII or Latin-1 per default. (It's binary-safe at least.)

Now parameters transferred via URL or form values usually get encoded as UTF-8. That will work in PHP, as UTF-8 was specifically designed to work with systems that are unaware of its existence.

The UTF-8 encoding of `ò` is `"\xC3\xB2"`. So when you access the first character in PHP with `$string[0]` it will only see the first byte, which is hex `C3` or decimal `195`.

There are the [`mb_string`](http://php.net/mb_string) functions in PHP however to deal with UTF-8 etc, if you need it. (The workaround here is to convert the string from UTF-8 to UCS-2 and then extract the first *word* to get the Unicode code point. Or longwinded approaches like [How to get code point number for a given character in a utf-8 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395832/how-to-get-code-point-number-for-a-given-character-in-a-utf-8-string))