# Using PHP to find unicode of a character

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get code point number for a given character in a utf-8 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395832/how-to-get-code-point-number-for-a-given-character-in-a-utf-8-string)

I have a sample code in javascript:

```
var str = "HELLO WORLD";
var n = str.charCodeAt(0);
```

This returns 72

How do I make this done in PHP?

Comment: `var_dump(ord('H'));` Not unicode as requested, but I'm not sure you know what unicode means ;)

Comment: Do you mean the [code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)?

Comment: @PeeHaa ... it isn't? It is `72` for both UTF-8 and UTF-16 AFAIK

Comment: PHP does not know anything about characters, it only works with bytes, so your string is probably encoded with UTF-8?

Comment: @PeeHaa Have you tried `"學".charCodeAt(0)`? It returns the UTF-16 value `23476`.

Comment: Sorry, `"學".charCodeAt(0)` should return `23416`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent of the above would be

```
$str = "HELLO WORLD";
$n = ord($str[0]);
```

Comment: I don't think that works for unicode, try: `$str="學"; $n = ord($str[0]);`

Comment: @AndreKRyou I guess M. Ahmad Zafar will work for Unicode

Answer (score 14):

**ASCII**

This will help:

```
//Code to Character
echo chr(65);

//Character to Code
echo ord('A');
```

**Unicode**

But since these function work for ASCII, for Unicode:

```
function uniord($u) {
    $k = mb_convert_encoding($u, 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8');
    $k1 = ord(substr($k, 0, 1));
    $k2 = ord(substr($k, 1, 1));
    return $k2 * 256 + $k1;
}

echo uniord('ب');
```

Answer (score 6):

Check [this contributed note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php#109812) in the docs here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

There's a function which returns the UTF-8 value, which is what I assume you want.

Comment: @AndreKR Ah, thanks! Was just looking through the HTML of the page to find the anchor but you beat me to it :-D

Comment: JavaScript's `charCodeAt` seems to return the UTF-16 value, at least on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

To be unicode aware you should try this one (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)

```
function uniord($u) {
    $k = mb_convert_encoding($u, 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8');
    $k1 = ord(substr($k, 0, 1));
    $k2 = ord(substr($k, 1, 1));
    return $k2 * 256 + $k1;
}
```