# Javascript function in PHP fromCharCode()

Tags: php, javascript

```
var test = String.fromCharCode(112, 108, 97, 105, 110);
document.write(test);

// Output: plain
```

Is there any PHP Code to work as `String.fromCharCode()` of javascript?

Comment: http://blog.stanislavstankov.com/2010/02/equal-function-string-fromcharcode-in-php/

Comment: You [first asked `String.charCodeAt`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989697/using-php-to-find-unicode-of-a-character) and now you're asking for the reverse?

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string) is what you want, because `String.fromCharCode` is basically UTF-16

Comment: This works better then the posted answers `IntlChar::chr(31337)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the `chr()` function:

> Returns a one-character string containing the character specified by
>   ascii.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

Comment: I don't think you are handling UTF-16, where `23416 -> "學"`

Answer (score 6):

PHP has [chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) function which would return one-character string containing the character specified by ascii

To fit your java script style you can create your own class

```
$string = String::fromCharCode(112, 108, 97, 105, 110);
print($string);
```

Class Used

```
class String {
    public static function fromCharCode() {
        return array_reduce(func_get_args(),function($a,$b){$a.=chr($b);return $a;});
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you are handling UTF-16, where `23416 -> "學"`

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(23476)` is `宴`

Answer (score 2):

***[The live demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4E3hDn)***

```
$output = implode(array_map('chr', array(112, 108, 97, 105, 110)));
```

And you could make a function:

```
function str_fromcharcode() {
    return implode(array_map('chr', func_get_args()));
}

// usage
$output = str_fromcharcode(112, 108, 97, 105, 110);
```

Comment: I don't think you are handling UTF-16, where `23416 -> "學"`

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(23476)` is `"宴"`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this..

```
 // usage: echo fromCharCode(72, 69, 76, 76, 79)
    function fromCharCode(){
      $output = '';
      $chars = func_get_args();
      foreach($chars as $char){
        $output .= chr((int) $char);
      }
      return $output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`chr()`](http://php.net/chr) function does this, however it only takes one character at a time. Since I'm not aware of how to allow a variable number of arguments in PHP, I can only suggest this:

```
function chrs($codes) {
    $ret = "";
    foreach($codes as $c) $ret .= chr($c);
    return $ret;
}
// to call:
chrs(Array(112,108,97,105,110));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `chr()` if you only need ASCII support.

```php
echo chr(120); // outputs "x"
```

Or its multi-byte twin `mb_chr()` if you need Unicode (requires [mbstring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension):

```php
echo mb_chr(23416); // outputs "學"
```

See:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-chr.php