# Special characters to HTML ASCII Entity Equivalent

Tags: php, function, ascii, special-characters, fckeditor

How will I convert all special characters to their corresponding html entity?

Special character would be like `$ & / \ { } ( - ' , @` etc.

I tried to use **htmlentities()** and **htmlspecialchars()**. But didn't solve my problem.

please check [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html). I want output like **Entity Number i.e. column 3**.

Actually the scenario is - I need to take input from **fckeditor**. and then save into the database. So I need to convert all special character to their corresponding html entity, from the text. Otherwise it's giving me error.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` ? http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran , I forgot to mention - I also tried htmlspecialchars(). but not get output

Comment: What is the expected output of `$` you are looking for as a HTML entity ?

Comment: for $ it would give &#36;

Comment: Get the character's code point, then format an SGML entity yourself by prepending `&#` and appending semicolon. For a head start, adjust the function proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395832/how-to-get-code-point-number-for-a-given-character-in-a-utf-8-string

Comment: @Ruud that's not suitable for me now. Because I need to convert special characters from an fckeditor input.

Comment: What about: `echo htmlspecialchars("&#" . ord('$') . ";");`

Comment: @divaka before commenting please check question properly.

Comment: @ripa - My comment is an example? What's wrong with it? Check the code for every special char you want.

Comment: @ripa Test it here for every symbol you want and see the output: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ then compare with the third column here http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html and tell me what I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: @divaka in my question, I've already mentioned htmlspecialchars() not working for me.

Comment: @ripa did you even test the code?? Pretty sure the way I wrote it is different from the way you've tested.

Comment: @ripa: I have a strong feeling you are not supplying us with all the details necessary to answer your question. In one of your comments you mentioned fckeditor; you did not tag it as such, nor was it mentioned in the question itself. Please edit your question; currently people are speculating about your intentions, which is a total waste of everybody's valuable time IMHO.

Comment: @ripa: Thanks for your edit, that really helps; though it still leaves me with many questions. You say you got an error while trying to store text in a database. What error? Which database engine? Accessed through which API? What makes you think HTML-encoding is the solution? Let's take a few steps back, and focus on the error before jumping to conclusions. Also, please show us some code where you write to the database; code often speaks louder than words.

Comment: I agree with @Ruud. What exactly is the problem you're encountering? It sounds like you have content being edited with FCKEditor -- give us an example of a problem with the text it returns. There are only a few things which need to be handled before shoving it into a database, so why are you trying to replace so many characters?

Comment: @ripa: No you didn't. At least not since my previous comment. Forgot to save your changes?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is for an ASCII equivalent of a character. So you need to make use of `ord()`.

By the way what [`divaka`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412896/divaka) mentioned is right.

Do like this..

```
<?php

function getHTMLASCIIEquiv($val)
{
    $arr=['$','&','/','\\','{','}','(','-','\'',',','@'];
    $val = str_split($val);$str="";
    foreach($val as $v)
    {
        if(in_array($v,$arr))
        {
        $str.="&#".ord($v).";";
        }
        else
        {
            $str.=$v;
        }
    }
    return $str;
}

echo getHTMLASCIIEquiv('please check $100 & get email from test@cc.com');
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
please check &#36;100 &#38; get email from test&#64;cc.com
```

[<kbd>**`Demo`**</kbd>](https://eval.in/94699)

Comment: please try for $char = "$ & / \ { } ( - ' ,"; this string. not giving me the mentioned output.

Comment: @ripa, It is working like as it should. Check out the demo in the answer.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran for an specific case it's working. but check You demo. I've posted actual string.

Comment: @ripa, You can't modify the demo I guess as it is IP based. Can you post it on your question or make your own demo and link it here ?

Comment: the text is "please check $100 & get email from test@cc.com"

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I'm pretty sure that ripa's problem is that browser or text editor or wherever she use this, is translating the entity into the corresponding symbols and she is seeing the entity, not the symbol itself!