# Different Variants of UTF-8 Comma? [，] [,] - CURL Response for MySQL Data

Tags: php, mysql, curl, encoding

Prepping a Curl Response for particular data to be inserted into a MySQL Table.

Noticed some special characters in the saved data for certain URL's.

```
$curldata = curl_exec($curl);
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($curldata);
```

brought back `ASCII` encoding.

Okay, don't want that.

The tables in my database are an `InnoDB` type with a `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation.

Added this to my curl options:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);
```

And an `iconv` function based on the above `mb_detect_encoding` / `$encoding` variable upon save.

```
$curldata = iconv($encoding, "UTF-8", $curldata);

// save to file to test output
file_put_contents('test.html', $curldata);
```

Not sure if this is the best way to go about this, but my `test.html` output no longer has any encoding for special characters, so... (perhaps) mission accomplished.

As I parse through the data, I then notice this character.

> ，

Not an ordinary comma... [Comparison: ,/，]

But acts like one. Try doing a `ctrl+f` and try to find a comma. It treats them as the same, and both as a UTF-8 character - `var_dump(mb_detect_encoding('，'));`

I look at my table row, and see it as a row inserted as such

> 8，8

If I try to search for a `,` it does indeed bring back the instances where `，`is present.

Vice versa, if I search for `，` it brings back all instances where that and a comma occurs.

Basically for all intents and purposes it is a comma, yet obviously isn't.

This is of course workable, but rather annoying and feels riddled with inconsistency.

Can anyone explain why the two commas are the same, yet obviously different?

Is there a solution for me to prevent these odd characters from entering my CURL response, or further in within my `DOM` response and `PDO` Insert.

edit:

If relevant,

```
// dom
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($curldata, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

// pdo
$pdoquery = "INSERT INTO `table` (`Attr`) VALUES (?)";
$value = "8，8";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`Attr`) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->execute([$value]);
```

edit 2:

Well, it appears to be a `FULLWIDTH COMMA`..

```
var_dump(utf8_to_unicode('，'));
```

> string '%uff0c' (length=6)

```
var_dump(utf8_to_unicode(','));
```

> string '%2c' (length=3)

Starting to make more sense... now to figure out how to prevent such characters from entering the curl response/DOM/database...

Comment: I agree, but that is seemingly only how it appears.  The browser, MySQL, PHP, so forth, all claim it to be the same character (a simple comma) [image link](https://i.imgur.com/E9V6acr.png)

Comment: https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php says `，,` is `%uFF0C%2C`, i.e. `%uFF0C` and a simple comma.

Comment: Yeah you got me thinking the same.  Made a second edit... based off this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395832/how-to-get-code-point-number-for-a-given-character-in-a-utf-8-string ... confusing how the browser interprets it as the same character though.  Now trying to figure out how to prevent non-standard UTF-8 characters in my responses

Comment: The curl requested site is also controlled by yourself? Or do you just try to replace some characters from a foreign response?

Comment: No, it's an external site.  Not exactly sure the ideal solution but I'm looking for maybe a function that will 'normalize' the string to standard utf-8 characters before my PDO/MySQL insert... hm

Comment: Isn't there any curl response header providing the actual encoding? Or a `<meta>` tag?

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` on the page and `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` in the headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189568/discussion-between-quasimodos-clone-and-brian-bruman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want the function `mb_convert_kana` which can convert characters of different widths into a uniform width.

```
$s = 'This is a string with ，, (commas having different widths)';

echo 'original : ', $s, PHP_EOL;
echo 'converted: ', mb_convert_kana($s, 'a');
```

result:

```
original : This is a string with ，, (commas having different widths)
converted: This is a string with ,, (commas having different widths)
```

PHP documentation: [mb_convert_kana](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-kana.php)
To get an idea what the meaning is, see also http://unicode.org/reports/tr11-2/

> By convention, 1/2 Em wide characters of East Asian legacy encodings are called "half-width" (or hankaku characters in Japanese), the others are called correspondingly "full-width" (or zenkaku) characters.

Answer (score 0):

With a suitable `COLLATION`, the two commas are treated as equal:

```
mysql> SELECT '，' = ',' COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
+----------------------------------------+
| '，' = ',' COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci  |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      0 |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT '，' = ',' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
+----------------------------------------+
| '，' = ',' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci  |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      1 |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT '，' = ',' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
+--------------------------------------------+
| '，' = ',' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci  |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          1 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It would be better to talk in terms of HEX, not unicode:

```
mysql> SELECT HEX('，'), HEX(',');
+------------+----------+
| HEX('，')  | HEX(',') |
+------------+----------+
| EFBC8C     | 2C       |
+------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```